# Save ArrayList in memory of the Android phone

Tags: java, android, arraylist, internal, fileoutputstream

It is to save an `ArrayList` by `FileOutputStream` in memory of an Android phone? Or you have any better method?

For example:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("Foto_Imovel", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 fos.write(My_Array_List.getBytes());
                 fos.close();
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you are looking for a recommendation, there really isn't enough detail in your question but you could probably get away with writing to `SharedPreferences`. If you are not looking for a recommendation, this question is unclear.

Comment: Thank you, That was it  !!!